# Laravel - Validator::make fails my unique rule

Tags: php, laravel, validation, controller

I'm trying to use a validation on 'name' as unique, but to be ignored if the objected that has that same name is the same object being updated.

The Validation keeps failing, can you help me figuring out why?

Validator Function - I'm using same validator function to both create and update and only need to apply the rule on the update.

```
protected function validator(array $data, Wharehouse $wharehouse = null)
    {
        //different validations for create and edit
        if($wharehouse != null){
            return Validator::make($data, [
                'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', Rule::unique('wharehouses')->ignore($wharehouse)],
                'espacoTotal' => ['required', 'numeric', 'max:60000']
            ]);
        }else{
            return Validator::make($data, [
                'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', Rule::unique('wharehouses')],
                'espacoTotal' => ['required', 'numeric', 'max:60000']
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Validation Call

```
protected function editById(Request $request)
    {

        $wharehouse = Wharehouse::find($request->wharehouse_id);

        $validation = $this->validator($request->all(),$wharehouse);

        if ($validation->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('/wharehouses')->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
        } else {
            $wharehouse->name = $request->input('name');
            $wharehouse->espacoTotal = $request->input('espaco');
            $wharehouse->save();
            return back()->with('create.success','Armazem actualizado com sucesso.');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try removing the class from the argument, leaving just `protected function validator(array $data, $wharehouse)`. Or check what you actually have on that $wharehouse variable

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I've checked the $wharehouse object and it has all the info, but still fails validation...

Answer (score 0):

Append the `id` of the instance currently being updated to the validator.

1. Pass the `id` of your instance to ignore the unique validator.
2. In the validator, use a parameter to detect if you are updating or
   creating the resource.

If updating, force the unique rule to ignore a given id: `unique:table,column,except,idColumn`

```
//rules
'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users,name,' . $userId],
```

Comment: I am already passing a parameter which is an object that has an `ID`
and as far as I researched `Rule::unique('wharehouses')->ignore($wharehouse)`is the same as
`//rules
'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users,name,' . $wharehouseId],` i'm just ignoring the same object instead of the id, which leads to the same end.

Comment: No, you have to pass the model id, not the whole model.